# Twitter streaming API : does the bandwidth is limited?

Tags: streaming, twitter

I would like to stream all the twitter tweets (Yes, I am crazy), in order to make some stats.
I have no special permission, I am just a simple twitter user.
To begin, I am just testing whether it is possible : I go on my server, it has a 100 Mbs bandwidth (I checked it is true),
and I run this command :

```
curl -d 'track=http' http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -umyuser:mypasswd | grep 'xxxxxx'
```

I put the 'grep' just to not have the tweets displayed and not have limitations due to displaying text on screen.
Then I used 'dstat' to check the bandwidth used : it is all the time limited to 128KB/s (that is only 1Mbs). As a tweet weight is about 2K, it seems I can stream only about 64 tweets per seconds... much less than the reality (more than 1000 tweets/s I believe...).
Event if I add some frequent term into the track list, The bandwidth is stuck to 128KB/s.

Do you have any idea to get the full streaming ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have been granted the privilege, you can't access the fully unmetered [firehose](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#statuses-firehose) stream.  With just basic privileges, you will be relegated to what you are doing now, using [filter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#statuses-filter), or using [sample](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#statuses-sample) (which will deliver approximately 1% of Twitter's tweet volume.)

You can *try* to gain elevated access by asking Twitter, however they don't seem to be handing elevated privileges out unless you can justify your use case pretty well.